# Position of permission prompt in screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, frontend

Is there a way to know the position of the permissions prompt (camera, geolocation, notifications, etc...) in the browser?

The reason why is that my app asks for allot of permissions and some of my users are not that tech savvy, so I want to make an arrow pointing to it, feels like a better user experience. I can get them from my displays but it wouldn't be responsive if I do that.

Does anyone know if there's an API/Workaround that allows this?

Thank you!

Comment: That is to protect user from unwanted access, remove that is went against user's policies, I reckon you can create friendly UI system, and as for permission only when needed.

Comment: Thanks, but my question still remains, I don't want to remove the permission prompt, I just want to make a responsive arrow pointing at it so the user knows where to click, for that I need to know the coordinates in the screen where the prompt appears